# How to record emails sent using Dacastro4 LaravelGmail in Laravel Telescope?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-telescope

I want to use Telescope to record and download all emails for an email web app. I have installed Laravel Telescope. And tried to analyze whether it records emails and all. It works fine with Laravel default Mail. But in my webapp, I am using Dacastro4 LaravelGmail Api to send emails. How can I modify Telescope implementations or anything so I can record
the emails sent using the API? So I can show them in the Telescope UI.

Telescope is recording all things except this functionality. It also records a request which I use to send email.

I am using Laravel 8.

the route I use to send email is  'API/Sendmail
the controller class name is 'MailController.php'
the model class name is 'App\Models\SentMail'
and I use 'Dacastro4\LaravelGmail\Services\Message\Mail;'

Below is the code after input validation

```
$mail = new Mail;
$mail->to($request->mail_to);
$mail->cc($request->cc);
$mail->bcc($request->bcc);
$mail->subject($finalMailSubject);
$mail->message($finalMailBody);
if (count($attachedFilesPath) > 0) {
    $mail->attach(...$attachedFilesPath);
}
$application->token_json);
$mail->send();

if (count($attachedFilesPath) > 0) {
    Storage::deleteDirectory($folder);
}
```